# Stackdriver unable to determine collectd endpoint

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver

All my hosts stopped reporting stats to collectd google gateway. This is due to some internal change on google side.

[image: missing stackdriver stats]

In logs files I see this:

```
Jan 13 08:52:36 ign-rpt01 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent...
Jan 13 08:52:36 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10768]: mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Jan 13 08:52:36 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10768]:  * Stopping Stackdriver metrics collection agent stackdriver-agent
Jan 13 08:52:37 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10768]:    ...done.
Jan 13 08:52:37 ign-rpt01 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent.
Jan 13 08:52:37 ign-rpt01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent...
Jan 13 08:52:37 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10794]: mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Jan 13 08:52:37 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10794]:  * Starting Stackdriver metrics collection agent stackdriver-agent
Jan 13 08:52:38 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10794]: Unable to determine collectd endpoint!
Jan 13 08:52:38 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10794]:  * not starting, configuration error
Jan 13 08:52:38 ign-rpt01 stackdriver-agent[10794]:    ...fail!
Jan 13 08:52:38 ign-rpt01 systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent.
Jan 13 08:53:16 ign-rpt01 extractd[10869]: Error sending processes data: Stackdriver gateway replied with a 401: <html><title>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</title><body>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</body></html>
Jan 13 08:54:16 ign-rpt01 extractd[10903]: Error sending processes data: Stackdriver gateway replied with a 401: <html><title>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</title><body>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</body></html>
Jan 13 08:55:16 ign-rpt01 extractd[10947]: Error sending processes data: Stackdriver gateway replied with a 401: <html><title>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</title><body>HTTP 401: Unauthorized (Invalid API key)</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I go to stackdriver account settings:

```
The following instances are using a deprecated configuration of the monitoring agent. Alerting policies referencing metrics from these agents do not work as intended and are currently unsupported. Dashboards using metrics from these agents are also unsupported and will soon stop working.
```

Please update your monitoring agent. [Learn more](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/troubleshooting)

Okay, it turns out that now only --write-gcm is supported now.

### TL;DR version

Just run this:

```
curl -O "https://repo.stackdriver.com/stack-install.sh"
sudo bash stack-install.sh --write-gcm
```

And hey, my stats are starting to come in again:
[image: stackdriver stats]

Comment: PS: I'm using ansible to automate my setup. Here's a patch for ansible role to get rid of API key: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-ansible-role/pull/23.diff